Using LaTeX packages in Quarto YAML for Typst output-formats
I want to use LaTeX packages in the Quarto YAML header for Typst output formats. A sketch of my YAML header is below. It seems that it doesn't work for \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}. The output shows usepackage[none]{hyphenat} after the author's name and document renders with hyphenation. Any hints, please?
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
format:
  typst:
    papersize: a4
    mainfont: Latin Modern Roman
    sansfont: Latin Modern Roman
    fontsize: 12pt
    margin:
      x: 1cm
      y: 1cm
    toc: false
    section-numbering: 1.1.a
    columns: 1
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
editor: visual
---


Typst isn't latex

FYI, backticks are used to mark up code (and file paths, etc.). “LaTeX”, “Quarto”, “YAML” and “Typst” are not code, they are names. Don’t use backticks for them.

As mentioned in a comment, latex packages are not compatible with Typst, since these are two different languages.
You'll have to find a way to achieve the desired effect in typst.
For example, to disable hyphenation:
format:
  typst:
    include-before-body:
      - text: |
          #set text(hyphenate: false)

References:

quarto typst includes
typst hyphenate rule

